# AWS Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to my EC2 instance and getting the following error.

Command I'm running: ssh -v -i key.pem ubuntu@[my instance address]

I changed the permissions on the key file to 600 as I've seen in other threads, but that didn't solve the problem.

Output I'm getting:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-247-2-128.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [54.247.2.128] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/avimeir/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/avimeir/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/avimeir/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/avimeir/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ae:42:29:3d:3e:c0:a8:04:7f:19:9c:c0:52:00:a4:1e
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-247-2-128.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/avimeir/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/avimeir/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ninja.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/avimeir/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to check:

1. The SSH keypair file
2. The username. For example: root, ec2-user, ubuntu, ...
3. The hostname of your server. For example, if you stop your instance, it will get a new IP address.

If you are using Ubuntu Cloud Guest official image, you can check the [Ubuntu EC2 Starter's Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide).

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve it by editing /etc/ssh_config (on OSX) and adding the following line:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```